# I created a new project in VS 2019 and it doesn't compile because VS fails to find Toolset v142

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, devtoolset

The 'template' for the new project is MFC Dynamic Link Library. The problem seems to boil down to Visual Studio looking for the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v142" - which doesn't exist. I have run and re-run the Visual Studio installer - always adding more things for toolset v142, but nothing seems to help. Is there some way to get this folder to appear? With the right stuff in it?

In reality, I am upgrading an existing project from umpteen versions back to be compiled with VS 2019. Because I could not get it to compile, I tried to create a new project to stuff with the files from my old project and the problem occurred before I even added any files to it.

I have done a similar process to compile my project for previous versions of VS, but never had this problem before. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you installed the [Desktop development with C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-160#step-4---choose-workloads) workload.

Comment: This issue is that your VS is always looks for the v142 toolset under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v142` and that path is not used of the new VS2019 version. It should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v142`.

Comment: Did you defined a new `VCTargetsPath` system environment variable and set an old,wrong value for it so that VS cannot find the right v142 toolset.

Comment: Since you new created project has also the error, so I think you have do some changes to system environment variable.

Comment: @dxiv - yes, that workload is installed.

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT: I did find a VCTargetsPath environment variable and deleted it. That fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove your issue, I have made a small test:

**1)** create a new system environment variable called `VCTargetsPath` and then set its value to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\
```

[image]

**2)** then restart VS and also set the the **Platfrom Toolset** to `v142`under **Project Properties**.

[image]

**3)** then rebuild the project and get the same error:

[image]

**Since** you new created project has also the error, so I think you have do some changes to system environment variable.

**Also**, you should note that this path is for old **VS2015**.

**However**, VS2019 uses:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v142
```

You make a change so that it will overwrite the system value for **VS2019** which leads to the issue. The value is  global and affects all the vs versions on your current PC.

**Suggestion**

**1)** You should check your system environment variable and search for `VCTargetsPath`, if you has this variable, please delete it.

**2)** or if you have this variable `VCTargetsPath`, change its value to, or if you do not have it, create it and set its value to **VS2019**.

[image]

Comment: I found an (USER) environment variable VCTargetsPath and deleted it. That fixed the problem for me. Thanks.